# selecting $xpath->evaluate using php

Tags: php, xpath

Hello I was wondering how I can evaluate the path using php. Here is the code:

```
  //Path I want to evaluate  -> (.*?)
  <p class="row" data-pid="(.*?)"><a href="(.*?)" class="i"><\/a>

  //method using php 
  $xpath->evaluate('string(.//a/@href)'
```

How can I evaluate the paths (.*?) using php?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to achieve. What do you want as result? `(.*?)` is no path, it is an attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but I assume you want to obtain the `href` attribute of the link, by the `data-pid` of it's ancestor `<p>` node.

If so, you need to use `query()` instead of `evaluate()`:

```
$datapin = 123;
$query = "//p[@data-pid='$dataPid']/a[@class='i']/@href";

$url = $xpath->query($query)->item(0)->nodeValue;
```